# Get publisher details at consumer end in Apache Active MQ

Tags: apache, activemq-classic, message-queue

Apache AMQ Producer and consumer are unaware of each other and they know only the broker they are connected to.
But is there any way consumer can know about the publisher? Any AMQ configuration which can let this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that is available in JMS, the spec defines decoupled producers and consumers.  You could attempt to discover the details you are looking for by monitoring the [advisory topics](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) that generate events for producers on Topics and Queues.